# Restart Sub with new parameters

Tags: vb.net

I have a question regarding the best way to re-enter a button_click event with new parameters, without the user having to click again.

Basically, the code searches for a string in an Excel worksheet. If the string is not found I would like it to prompt the user to change the worksheet and then have the code search again.

Obviously a GOTO from the [' FROM HERE] comment to the [' TO HERE] comment would do exactly what I want, but since GOTO is treated like a plague I decided I should probably stay away from it.

Any other ways to do this?

```
Private Sub button1_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button1.Click


If (radioButton1.IsChecked) Then
    Dim Choice As String = My.Application.myYear
    ' TO HERE
    If Not (My.Application.XLws Is My.Application.XLwb.Worksheets(Choice)) Then
        My.Application.XLws = My.Application.XLwb.Worksheets(Choice)
    End If

    Dim SearchStr As String = Trim(textBox1.Text)
    If Not (SearchStr.Contains(" ")) Then
        SearchStr = SearchStr.Insert(2, " ")
    End If

    Dim rRng As Long
    rRng = LastUsedCell(My.Application.XLws).item2
    Debug.Print(SearchStr)

    Dim SrcR As String = "A" & rRng
    Dim Serials As Excel.Range = My.Application.XLws.Range("A1", SrcR)
    Dim fRange As Excel.Range = ExcelFind(Serials, SearchStr)

    ' If no serial is found, prompt for a new year
    If (fRange Is Nothing) Then
        Debug.Print("Serial not found")
        Choice = InputBox("Try another year", "Serial not found in " & My.Application.myYear, "Auto", 100, 100)
        ' FROM HERE
        Return
    End If
    ' etc
```

Comment: Just put your search code in a function that returns `true` or `false` if it finds the string. Then on your button just call that function as often as you want.

Comment: If you need to do that, then you should create a subfunction

Comment: @Pierre - What exactly is a "subfunction"?  VB.Net has `Sub`s and `Function`s.  I've never heard of a subfunction before.

Comment: I just mean a "function" (sub or function, I don't care) which is called by the main function, to avoid duplicating code

Comment: If you really want the code to stay in the button click event, put all the relevant code in a `Do..Loop Until Not IsNothing(fRange)`